# Экономический бот Discord

Tags: python, бот, discord, события, disnake

Я недавно начал разработку своего бота на python с использованием библиотеки disnake, но столкнулся с проблемой, я хочу реализовать событие которое будет начислять пользователю 1 северную валюту за 1 минуту в голосовой канале, а так же за каждое сообщение длинной 10+ символов но не знаю как это сделать. Помогите поэалуйста